# How do I find the table for an ItemType in IBM Content Manager 8.4

Tags: content-management-system, db2

Given the item type name how do i find the underlying table on the IBM Content manager 8.4 Library Server database?

The database name is usually ICMNLSDB and the Scehma name is usually ICMADMIN

Answer (score 2):

To find the underlying first run the below query against the ICMADMIN Schema substituting the $$ItemType$$ for your item type name

```
SELECT k2.keywordcode comptypeid, k2.keywordname comptypename
FROM icmstnlskeywords k1, icmstnlskeywords k2, icmstcompdefs ct
WHERE k1.keywordclass = 2 
AND k1.keywordname = '$$ItemType$$' 
AND k1.keywordcode = ct.itemtypeid 
AND k2.keywordclass = 5 
AND k2.keywordcode = ct.componenttypeid 
AND k2.keywordname = '$$ItemType$$'
```

The COMPTYPEID can now be used to find your table the convention for the tables is the name:

ICMADMIN.ICMUTnnnnn001

Where the nnnnn is the COMPTYPEID from the previous query prefixed with leading zeros. This will then give the attributes and the ids required for generating the CMBItems. These details can be found on the IBM website by googleing the table names.

Answer (score 2):

Example: Item type ICCFilesytem

Step 1: Get ComponentTypeId from icmstnlskeywords table

Query:

```
select * from icmstnlskeywords where keywordclass=5 and keywordname = ‘ICCFilesytem;
//Result 1055
```

Step 2: Form ICMUT(IBM Content Manager User Table) table name using

```
ComponentTypeId 1055
ICMUT01055001
where

ICMUT(Keyword)

01055(ComponentTypeId of 5 digit)

001(Segment Id by default 001)
```

Step 4: Get Documents in ICCFilesytem

Query:

```
Select * from ICMUT01055001;
```